# Ms Access Web App (AWA) - Data macro to get data from one table to another table in

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, sharepoint-apps, ms-access-web-app

My question is related to Ms Access Webapp.

I have 2 Tables (Fields):

**User Entry - Primary Data (SAP ID, Project Name, Project Manager)**

**User Entry - Planning Data (SAP ID (lookup from prev table), Project Name (lookup from prev table), Project Manager (lookup from prev table), many more values (not lookups from prev table))**

I want to know how can I import values entered in

**User Entry - Primary Data (SAP ID, Project Name, Project Manager)**

to

**User Entry - Planning Data (SAP ID (lookup from prev table), Project Name (lookup from prev table), Project Manager (lookup from prev table), many more values (not lookups from prev table))**

what data macro to be used? or insert event or anything else.

Note: while answering please use my terms and answer please.

Thanks & Regards,
Satish Kumar G N

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could simply use the on insert macro of User Entry table to call a data macro, ie "import_user_entry" taking SAP ID, Project Name and Project Manager as parameters. In this data macro, you will use the Create Record block.